# openssl encrypt by specifying AES 256 key instead of passphrase

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography

I need to encrypt some data using aes-256-ecb since a backend code expects it as a configuration. I'm able to encrypt using a key which is derived from a passphrase using:

```
openssl enc -p -aes-256-ecb -nosalt -pbkdf2 -base64 -in data-plain.txt -out data-encrypted.txt | sed 's/key=//g'
```

This encrypts using derived key and outputs the key in console.

However, I couldn't find how to do it with a generated key, something like:

1. Generate a 256-bit key using:

   openssl rand -base64 32 > key.data
2. Then use this key during encryption, with something like:

   openssl enc -p -aes-256-ecb **-key=key.data** -nosalt -pbkdf2 -base64 -in data-plain.txt -out data-encrypted.txt

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the key in hex using `-K`. Note that you also need to specify the IV with `-iv` for some ciphers and modes of operation. You will also need to add `-nopad` for ECB decryption if you are decrypting a raw AES block (i.e. no padding is used). Be aware that ECB is highly insecure if used to encrypt more than one block.

Comment: There's no problem doing ECB either with padding or without (for exact block multiples only) as long as you're consistent: decryption must = encryption, and in this Q where 'backend' is fixed encryption must = expected. Otherwise concur.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't get the -nopad comment though, the Java code is using "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding" configuration, openssl seems to use PKCS5 as default padding, and it's working.